# What is the fastest kart and character configuration in Mario Kart 8?

Tags: mario-kart-8

In Mario Kart 8, handling attributes such as `speed`, `acceleration`, and `traction` are affected by 4 factors: The weight class of the character, the kart or bike, the type of wheels, and the glider attachment.

Including Mario Kart 8's current DLC, what is the fastest possible configuration?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've got a combination that gives 5.75 speed out of 6:

> The combination with the fastest top speed is Wario/Bowser/Morton in the Mach 8/Sports Coupe/Circuit Special/Gold Standard with Slick/Cyber Slick tires and any glider. This gives you a speed of **5.75/6**

[Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/700050-mario-kart-8/69327057/785080388)